# Python - Getting a value from json and storing it in a variable

Tags: python, json

I hava file1.py that contains json data like this :

```
data = '{"env":"production","user_id":"8xxxx0-f1xx-xxx6-bxxx-0a1xf6dxxxx","c_id":"ca0cad8xxxxe68962810d8axxxxb6a"}'
```

I'm trying to get values from file1.py and assign it to local variables like this:

```
import file1
import json

json_data = file1.data

env = json_data["env"]
user_id = json_data["user_id"]
channel_id = json_data["c_id"]
```

But i always get :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

i search for smilar errors and found a lot ,but non of them fixed my problem .

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: You need to use `json.loads()` to parse the JSON in the file into a dictionary.

Comment: You have to load the json string into a Python object using `json.loads`

Comment: Why does `file1.py` contain JSON instead an ordinary dictionary?

Comment: `data = '...'` This is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Change it to `data = { ... }` without the quotes..

Comment: Even if it's not the only thing, why does it need to be a string instead of a dictionary? JSON is normally used when getting values over the network or from text files, there's no need to use it for variables in programs.

Comment: @Barmar because the value is written to this file in this form by another application  and I'm only using the python script to get the value , i can't change the way it is written in this file unfortunately

Comment: testing it again and now json.loads() works thanks a lot to you all , @Barmar you can submit this as an answer to be accepted